Blazor: Properly resolve scoped service from App.razor (.NET 8)
I am following this example on passing tokens from HttpContext to components in a SSR application. It mentions the following:

An alternative to assigning the initial state to the TokenProvider in the preceding example is to copy the data into a scoped service within OnInitializedAsync for use across the app.

However, it seems that resolving the scoped service from App.razor causes it to initialized twice:
App.razor:
@inject Service Service

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlazorSandbox.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)" />
<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

@code {

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        Service.Foo = 123;


        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

}

Home.razor:
@page "/"
@inject Service Service

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Service.Foo: @Service.Foo

Service.Foo is 0 here.
I've seen similar issues with scoped services getting initialized twice. These were related to prerendering though, which is already disabled in my case. Browsing a bit further through the documentation I could find the following info:

The App component is always rendered statically even if prerendering of a page component is disabled. Therefore, injecting services via the top-level imports file results in resolving two instances of the service in page components.

I am assuming this also applies to services resolved directly via @Inject. Is there any workaround for this? I need to initialize the service from a location where HttpContext is guaranteed to be available. AFAICT this is only the case for App.razor (formerly _Host.cshtml)?

Have you looked at PersistentComponentState.  The documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerender?view=aspnetcore-8.0#persist-prerendered-state

This document is for .net7 "Blazor Server App". But .net8 has some significant structure changes and the template called "Blazor Web App" which you could aslo choose Server rendermode.
_host.cshtml (.net7) => App.razor (.net8)  
App.razor (.net7)    => Routes.razor (.net8) 
_host.cshtml (.net7)/ App.razor (.net8) is always SSR rendermode. They have to be SSR because they are entrance page that process traditional Http Request into SPA (other rendermodes). 
In .net7, you will find the code <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" /> in _host.cshtml to set rendermode for App.razor .
Similarly, in .net8. <Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false)" /> is to set remdermode for Routes.razor.
The service you inject in SSR and InterActiveServer(false) modes are never the same one. And according the changes ,you will need initialize the service in the Route.razor which has the same rendermode as Home.razor.

Initializing the service in Route.razor was a good hint. I managed to pass all the necessary info from App.razor to Route.razor (via [Parameter]) and populated the service there. Seems to work just fine.
